# c++ macro using variable from an other macro

Tags: c++, macros, switch-statement

I need to make `foo` compile by implementing the macros for it:

```
int foo(std::string tag)
{
    SWITCH_STRING(tag)
    {
        STRING_CASE(a)
        {
            return 1;
        }

        STRING_CASE(b)
        {
            return 2;
        }

        STRING_CASE(abc)
        {
            return 3;
        }

        STRING_ELSE
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

I would like to use the `tag` parameter in `SWITCH_STRING(tag)` and compare it to the `letter` parameter in `STRING_CASE(letter)`, to implement this switch like syntax, I'm stuck for a while and new to macros in c++ could you offer a solution to how to implement the macros please?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

// Write macros here | 
#define SWITCH_STRING(tag)
#define STRING_CASE(letter) letter == tag ? true : false
#define STRING_ELSE
```

Comment: I will never understand why people prefer to use macros so heavily in their codebases. Just use canonical C++ without the unnecessarily obfuscation.

Comment: why `letter == tag ? true : false` instead of simply `letter == tag`? And then I also wonder what the macro is good for. `STRING_CASE(letter)` isnt even less to type than `letter == tag`...

Comment: @CoryKramer I understand, but in this case it is part of a tutorial to macros, I need to learn them atleast.

Comment: @idclev463035818 its wrong just an attempt of mine, I dont think you can even compare tag with letter cause they are not part of the same macro definition?

Comment: Pretty sure this is a circular dependency issue so in short you can't use `A` in `B` if `B` depends on `A` (since one has to be declared first)

Comment: start by writing the code you would get after expansion of the macros. An ordinary `switch` cannot switch on `string`s, so how do you want to realize it?

Comment: tip: you dont have to use `tag` in the cases, if you use `SWITCH_STRING` to assign to a hidden temporary, eg `my_tag = tag;` and then compare the `letter`s to `my_tag`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have to admit: Macros can be fun. We all should know that they should be avoided. Though, as this is an exercise about macros, we can put the discussion whether to use a macro or not aside.

The point of the exercise is that you cannot (directly) switch on a `std::string`. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60803413/4117728) shows how this limitation can be worked-around. Being required to write exremely verbose repetetive code, the macro is kind of justified. For the sake of completeness I want to add how it can be solved using your original approach, using a series of `if` instead of the `switch`.

First, I write the function that does what is asked for without any macro involved:

```
int foo(std::string tag)
{
    std::string& temp = tag;
    {
        if (temp == "a") 
        {
            return 1;
        }
        if (temp == "b")
        {
            return 2;
        }
        if (temp == "abc")
        {
            return 3;
        }
        {
            return -1;
        }
    }
}
```

It isnt that nice that it uses `if`s not `else if` that should be prefered for mutually exclusive cases. However, as each case `return`s, the result wont differ (if that isnt the case, you'll have to add some `goto` vodoo as outlined in the other answer). Having that, it is straightforward to see what macros are needed:

```
#define SWITCH_STRING(tag) std::string& temp = tag;
#define STRING_CASE(X) if (temp == #X)
#define STRING_ELSE
```

This kind of answers your question about how to use the parameter of one macro in a second one: You don't. Instead you can use a reference whose name does not depend on the actual name of `tag` anymore.

[Full example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/X33sofzahbmnV9MU)

Answer (score 1):

What you might do to switch on string:

```
constexpr std::size_t myhash(std::string_view) { /* .. */ }

int foo(const std::string& tag)
{
    switch (tag)
    {
        case myhash("a"): { return 1; }
        case myhash("b"): { return 2; }
        case myhash("abc"): { return 3; }
        default: { return -1; }
    }
}
```

That doesn't need MACRO.

If you have collisions with your cases, compilation would fail (same value in `switch`)
and you will need another hash function.

If you want to prevent collisions (from input string), you might do:

```
constexpr std::size_t myhash(std::string_view) { /* .. */ }

int foo(const std::string& tag)
{
    switch (tag)
    {
        case myhash("a"): { if (tag != "a") { goto def; } return 1; }
        case myhash("b"): { if (tag != "b") { goto def; } return 2; }
        case myhash("abc"): { if (tag != "abc") { goto def; } return 3; }
        default: { def: return -1; }
    }
}
```

which might indeed be less verbose with MACRO

```
#define CaseHash(str, c) case myhash(c): if (str != c) { goto def; }
#define DefaultHash default: def
```

to result to

```
constexpr std::size_t myhash(std::string_view) { /* .. */ }

int foo(const std::string& tag)
{
    switch (tag)
    {
        CaseHash(tag, "a") { return 1; }
        CaseHash(tag, "b") {  return 2; }
        CaseHash(tag, "abc") {  return 3; }
        DefaultHash: { return -1; }
    }
}
```

Comment: shouldnt `myhash` return something?

Comment: @idclev463035818: Sure, typo fixed, even if other types might also be valid.

Comment: I wonder, do you really use something like this in real code? I rarely use `switch`, but rather plain `if-if else`, so I never actually encountered the problem. Imho it is a nice exercise for using a macro, but has it any value beyond that?

Comment: @idclev463035818: We use the first version in our code base (so no macro), (input is under control so no collisions prevention needed). Harder to use `constexpr` hash with if else chain.

Comment: oh i see. First time I realize that particular advantage of `switch` that you need to have unique values. Thanks for clarification